# Ruby on Rails, taking data from Graphql and posting on it to Facebook-messenger

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, facebook-graph-api, graphql

```
  $message_text = message.text
  module STAPI
    HTTP = GraphQL::Client::HTTP.new("API_ADDRESS")
    Schema = GraphQL::Client.load_schema(HTTP)
    Client = GraphQL::Client.new(schema: Schema,execute: HTTP)
  end

  module Sticker
    Query = STAPI::Client.parse <<-'GRAPHQL'
      {
        stickers(query: "#{$message_text}", first: 21, after: "") {
          edges {
            node {
              fileUrl(fullWatermarked: true)
            }
          }
        }
      }
    GRAPHQL
  end

  result = STAPI::Client.query(Sticker::Query)
```

First of all this is an messenger bot and with this messenger bot i am taking users input and i am searching the input in our database then i post something related with the input.

So, in the code i can't search beacuse, in my opinion `query: "#{$message_text}"` is broken.

I take users input with `message.text` . This input comes like this 'Hello' (with '). But i need to give  `query: "#{$message_text}"` part like this "Hello"(with "). how can i give messenger.text to query part like this "Hello"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe you already know how to make this work based on what you wrote in your [other question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40206479/how-to-define-dynamic-variables-on-graphql). For others facing the same problem, take a look at [variables](https://facebook.github.io/graphql/#sec-Language.Variables). Your example would become as follows:

```
$message_text = message.text
module STAPI
  HTTP = GraphQL::Client::HTTP.new("API_ADDRESS")
  Schema = GraphQL::Client.load_schema(HTTP)
  Client = GraphQL::Client.new(schema: Schema,execute: HTTP)
end

module Sticker
  Query = STAPI::Client.parse <<-'GRAPHQL'
    query Q($message: String) {
      stickers(query: $message, first: 21, after: "") {
        edges {
          node {
            fileUrl(fullWatermarked: true)
          }
        }
      }
    }
  GRAPHQL
end

result = STAPI::Client.query(Sticker::Query, variables: {message_text: $message_text})
```