# How to define dynamic variables on Graphql?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, graphql

So, I am working on ruby on rails. This is my code:

```
require 'graphql/client'
require 'graphql/client/http'

HTTP = GraphQL::Client::HTTP.new("Graph-API-Web-Site")
Schema = GraphQL::Client.load_schema(HTTP)
Client = GraphQL::Client.new(schema: Schema,execute: HTTP)


Query = Client.parse <<-'GRAPHQL'
  query($message: String = "Hello") {
    stickers(query: $message, first: 21, after: "") {
      edges {
        node {
          fileUrl(fullWatermarked: true)
        }
      }
    }
  }
GRAPHQL


result = Client.query Query

puts result.data.inspect
```

How can I give specific value to stickers `{query: .....}` area? I want to change the value of message with program runs. For example when the message changes the `Client.query` should return something  different.

Comment: One important note. **Don't use variables beginning with $**, those are considered GLOBAL VARIABLES in Ruby, you can face really unexpected behavior because of that!

Comment: @Fire-Dragon-DoL: Those are not Ruby variables. Those are GraphQL variables, inside a GraphQL query, itself inside the `GRAPHQL` heredoc.

Comment: Oh damn, sorry, I completely misread that, forgive me! Guess the syntax highlight tricked me badly

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have just solved my problem via changing `result = Client.query Query`  ===> `result = Client.query Query, variables: { message: "hello" }`